# Jar works on another computer, not one that created it

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have created a simple java swing program in NetBeans.  After I finish with the code I do the "Clean and Build Main Project" and get a jar file.

I then try to run it and I get "Could not find main class"  But when I run it through the console it works fine.  So I copy all of the files that NetBeans created and put them on a flash drive and took them to a laptop.  I got the same message on the laptop so I looked at the manifest.mf.  I added the line with the main class and where it was located and it actually worked.  I would double click the jar and it worked perfectly.

So I thought I could go back to the computer that created the project and make the EXACT same changes and it would work.  I was wrong, I got the "Could not find the main class" error again.

I really don't understand this because of the following:

**Both computers are running Windows 7**

**Both computers are running the same version of Java**

**Both computers have the EXACT same directories where the jar file is**

**Both computers have the EXACT same files including manifest.mf**

**Both computers have the same PATH and CLASS PATH in the environment variables section**

It just seems really odd that the computer I created this program with can not run it via double click but another one can.  **Is there another setting on the computer that might be preventing it from running the jar via double click?**

EDIT: Got the "Could not find main class" error fixed by updating to the latest java.  I just tested it on another desktop pc by zipping the folder and it ran fine with double click.  I can run the jar from the console fine (on original pc), but when I double click..the cursor changes to the waiting symbol for a half second then stops and nothing else happens.  The java versions are the same, paths are the same, and the jar file is being opened by Java(TM)Platform SE binary.  Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

not an answer, are you done with ???

you have to set main class in the project properties

[image]

please ignore value in the VM Option

Comment: Yeah this might be it... But if you tried to run the project inside of Netbeans it asks what is the main class is an Netbeans remembers it...

Comment: The Main Class is set in the project properties just like it states in the manifest.mf.

Answer (score 0):

did you install nokia ovi suite...??
if yes then you have to launch jar file with **Java(TM) Platform SE binary**.....

Comment: No, I did not instal nokia ovi suite and the computers default program for opening jars is Java(TM) Platform SE binary.